# enum problem in mysql field

Tags: mysql

I have added a new enum column, enum('true','false') in an existing MySQL table.  What I am getting is whole table default enum field 'true' as default value.  I haven't set anything default, why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html):

> If an ENUM column is declared to
>   permit NULL, the NULL value is a legal
>   value for the column, and the default
>   value is NULL. If an ENUM column is
>   declared NOT NULL, its default value
>   is the first element of the list of
>   permitted values.